# Как прибавить к строке одну единицу десятичных?

Tags: php

Создать отдельную функцию где результат будет новая строка

```
$num1 = '0'; // '1'
$num2 = '0.0'; // '0.1'
$num3 = '0.00'; // '0.01'
$num4 = '0.000'; // '0.001'
$num5 = '0.0000'; // '0.0001' и тд.

function placePlus($num) {
  return '0.1';
}

$result = placePlus($num2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да хотя бы вот так, воспользовавшись функцие **substr**:

```
$num1 = '0'; // '1'
$num2 = '0.0'; // '0.1'
$num3 = '0.00'; // '0.01'
$num4 = '0.000'; // '0.001'
$num5 = '0.0000'; // '0.0001' и тд.

function placePlus($num) {
  return substr($num, 0, -1).'1';
}

echo placePlus($num1);
```

Или с помощью функции **substr_replace**:

```
function placePlus($num) {
  return substr_replace($num, '1', -1, 1);
}
```